# Adding script bash variables to awk and inotify

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, inotify

I want to create a script that will log every access of a directory or any file from that directory during a day, for that, I use inotifywait, but I don't like the output even though i formated it, I need the user that accessed/modified the file as well. And I want to print it in the table format. Something like this:

```
TIME               USER     FILE            EVENT
%mm:%HH PM/am      root     /home/root/x    Accesed(or anything the inotifywait gives)
```

And I tried something like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

watchedDir=$1
logFileName="$(date +'%d.%m.%Y').log"

iwait() {
    inotifywait -r -m --timefmt "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S" --format "%T;%w%f;%e" $watchedDir >> "$PWD/.$logFileName.tmp"
}

write_to_file() {
    while true; do
    last_entry=$(tail -n 1 "$PWD/$logFileName.tmp")
    time=$(tail -n 1 "$PWD/$logFileName.tmp" | cut -f1 -d';')
    user=$(stat $last_entry --format="%U")
    file=$(tail -n 1 "$PWD/$logFileName.tmp" | cut -f2 -d';')
    event=$(tail -n 1 "$PWD/$logFileName.tmp" | cut -f3 -d';')

    awk -v time="$time" -v user="$user" -v file="$file" -v event="$event" 'BEGIN {printf("%s %8s %8s %8s \n" ,"Time", "User", "File", "Event")}
    {printf("%s %s %s %s\n", time, user, file, event)}' >> "$PWD/.$logFileName.tmp"
    done
}

if [ "$(realpath $watchedDir)" != "$PWD" ]
then
    iwait &
    write_to_file &
    wait
fi
```

I also found out that if I try to watch the current directory and also redirect the file into the current directory it will flood the ouput... so I tried to get over that using that `if`.

How can I do something like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternative solution using `iwatch`

```
iwatch -c "./log.sh %f %e" ./test_iwatch/
```

`log.sh`

```
#!/bin/sh

d=$(date -u --rfc-3339='seconds')
u=$(stat -c '%U' "$1")

printf "%s %8s %8s %8s\n"  "$d" "$u" "$1" "$2" >> log.log
```

Resulted log example:

```
2020-11-13 21:48:41+00:00     user ./test_iwatch//29 IN_MOVED_TO
2020-11-13 21:49:11+00:00     user ./test_iwatch//220 IN_CREATE
2020-11-13 21:49:11+00:00     user ./test_iwatch//220 IN_CLOSE_WRITE
2020-11-13 21:51:51+00:00          ./test_iwatch//20 IN_ISDIR,IN_MOVED_FROM
2020-11-13 21:51:51+00:00     user ./test_iwatch//30 IN_ISDIR,IN_MOVED_TO
```

For more control on tabulation, try this

```
printf "%s\t%-16s\t%-24.24s\t%-16s\n"
```

Output will be like:

```
2020-11-13 22:21:38+00:00   user                ./test_iwatch//blue         IN_CREATE       
2020-11-13 22:21:38+00:00   user                ./test_iwatch//blue         IN_CLOSE_WRITE  
2020-11-13 22:21:44+00:00                       ./test_iwatch//blue         IN_MOVED_FROM   
2020-11-13 22:21:44+00:00   user                ./test_iwatch//red          IN_MOVED_TO
```

Format "-%X.Yf":

- `-` align left
- `X` minimum width (pad)
- `Y` maximum width (trim)
- `\t` & `\n` escape chars TAB & NEWLINE

Comment: Hello! thanks for answering, can we print those in a table format?

Comment: @C.Cristi yes, it is same printf of C language  format of `%X.Yf` , Do you want to trim long paths?

Comment: What do you mean trim long paths? Sure

Comment: @C.Cristi could you check update if something like that

Comment: @C.Cristi Because long path gonna break the table, so either trim them with maximum length or move long data to the last column.